# How to update Tab controller length base on Bloc loaded topics from shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have home Bloc which is load a `List<String>` from preferences package, then I want to Update my TabBar and TabBarView base on that so I need first to set TabController length but I dont know how to perform it here is my code.

##### HomeDataState

```dart
abstract class HomeDataState {}

class HomeDataInitialState extends HomeDataState{}

class HomeDataLoadingState extends HomeDataState {}

class HomeDataLoadedState<T> extends HomeDataState {
  final T data;
  HomeDataLoadedState({required this.data});
}

class HomeDataErrorState extends HomeDataState {
  final String error;

  HomeDataErrorState({required this.error});

}
```

##### BLOC

```dart
 Future<void> _loadAllFeed(
    HomeLoadAllFeed event,
    Emitter<HomeBlocState> emit,
  ) async {
    log('loading home feed..');

    /// emit loading all data
    emit(state.copyWith(
        newHeadLineState: HomeDataLoadingState(),
        newTopicDataState: HomeDataLoadingState()));

    /// fetches the headline news for country
    final headLineResponse = await _newsRepository.fetchHeadLineNews();

    /// gets the first topic from selected list
    final List<String>? userTopics = await _prefOperator.getUserTopics();
    topics = userTopics??[];

    /// gets the news based on the topic
    final firstTopicNews =
        await _newsRepository.getNewsBaseOnTopic(userTopics?.first ?? 'Car');

    /// if states was success for both
    if (headLineResponse is DataSuccess && firstTopicNews is DataSuccess) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
            newHeadLineState: HomeDataLoadedState(data: headLineResponse.data),
            newTopicDataState: HomeDataLoadedState(data: firstTopicNews.data),
            newUserTopicDataState: HomeDataLoadedState(data: userTopics)),
      );
    

  }
```

untill now every thing is ok  but I dont know how to give my TabController length in Ui.

this error I got when I use `context.watch`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use context.read() as once the controller is initiated in init method once when the state changes it can't process any watch function rather what you do is give the controller value once